# Dynamic variable creation using const

Tags: javascript, string, constants

How to create the following variables:

```
const city = 'Your city';
const state = 'your state';
const country = 'Country';
```

From the input variable

```
const address = "Your city, your state, your country";
```

Are there any methods to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: `.split` the string and then assign `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]` is the result to the appropriate constants…?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to tackle this problem. If the string is always in the format of `value1 <comma> value2 <comma> value3` you can easily use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get an array from the String and then assign the constants to the array indexes:

```js
let address = "Your city, your state, your country";

address = address.split(", ");

const city = address[0];
const state = address[1];
const country = address[2];

console.log(city, state, country);
```

With ES6 you can use destructuring assignments to make this even shorter:

```js
let address = "Your city, your state, your country";

address = address.split(", ");

const [city, state, country] = address;

console.log(city, state, country);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
    const address = "Your city, your state, your country";
    const splits = address.split(", ");

    const city = splits[0];
    const state = splits[1];
    const country = splits[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this

```
const { 2: city, 3: state, 4: country } = address.split(', ');

console.log(city, state, country);
```